# Microservices async operation HTTP response

Tags: http, asynchronous, architecture, microservices, event-driven

We're building a microservice app where clients can create *projects*. The following diagram shows the technical flow of this process:

[image: Create Project Flow]

My question: **what HTTP response should the API gateway return to the client (step 1.)?**

My initial idea was to give back a 202, but the problem there is that I don't know the `Location` yet (`/projects/{id}`), because the id of the *project* will be created at the Project Management Service.

Comment: When do you generate IDs, before/when the command is created (i.e. GUIDs) or after the `project` is persisted (i.e. autoincremented primary keys)?

Comment: The project id is generated by the Project Management Service. So after it receives the command and before it publishes the event.

Comment: Too bad, this complicates things. So, when you return the response to the client you don't know what is the ID of the project nor the status of the command, right?

Comment: That's right. The only thing we know is that the command is acknowledged.

Comment: So, you will need a `command id` that is generated by the api gateway and returned to the client like this: `/pending/commands/1234-abcd-5678-efgh`

Comment: And at this endpoint `/pending/commands/1234-abcd-5678-efgh` the client can query the result of the `command` or the `url` to the `project` if is already created

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a good solution. It's only a bit unpractical for us, to keep track of all the commands in our gateway.

Comment: It is the price to pay for fire-and-forget command style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the IDs of the newly created `project` entity is not known at the request time (i.e. it is generated after the insertion into the database) you indeed cannot generate the url to the `project` resource.

Instead, you could assign an ID (i.e. `1234-abcd-5678-efgh`) to the command before sending to the bus and keep track of its execution status on the API gateway itself. Then you can respond to the client with an command execution status endpoint like `/commands/1234-abcd-5678-efgh` where it can query by polling.

The alternative would be to use another service that would reserve&deliver unique IDs but you must make a blocking call to it and this hurts scalability. Or you can host this service inside the API gateway itself (onto the same node) to minimize latency. Also, there is a risk of loosing some IDs in case of project creation failures but this can be compensated by releasing those IDs in those situations (thus increasing the architecture complexity).

A third solution could be the use of a `project` surogate ID, like a GUID, assigned as a property of the `project`, included in the command, having the purpose of an alternate  identity that can be used only in the pre-creation phase of the process. Then, the response to the client could be like this: `/projects/by-guid/1234-abcd-5678-efgh` and after the `project` is created a `GET` to this `url` would permanently redirect to the final project url.